# i want to add a statement that repeats the condition whenever the user inputs a 'Y' on 'N' using scanner

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StepNumber {
    public static void main(String[] Diamond){
        int Start= 0,End= 0,Step= 0 ;
        Scanner jd=new Scanner (System.in);
        try{
        System.out.println("Input Starting Number:");
        Start=jd.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input Ending Number:");
        End=jd.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input Step Number:");
        Step=jd.nextInt();
        }catch(NumberFormatException j){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        while(Start<= End){
            System.out.println(Start);
            Start=Start+Step;
        }
    } 
}
```

/* PLS HELP ME GUYS i need this before wednesday... i want to ask the user to input  a letter weather  'y' or 'n' if he       picks 'y' the statemet in while loop will be re run 
and the user will input a new number in  "start", "end" and "step"*/

Comment: try using if else conditions first and then post the code, if problems

Comment: what do you mean? can you   do it for me? Still a new bee in java...haha :D but  when the program has been done i can easily analyze the pattern... and i can make it on my own..(I need an Example.. )

Comment: hey guys.. what application can you recommend best to download  in ipad  so that i can install and study it...

Comment: how come it's duplicate..? i created it my self...